# Tensorflow basics, tf.less calculation error

Tags: python, tensorflow

Lets assume that i want to calculate the operation:

```
[[1   2   3   4 ],     [1      [[1  2  3   4],
[5   6   7   8 ],       2       [10 12 14  16],
[9   10  11  12],   x   3   =   [27 30 33  36],
[13  14  15  16]]       4]      [42  56  60  64]]
```

just tried to do it in tensorflow with the following approach:

```
inputs=tf.ones((2,10,10,5))

# generate random tensor in shape (10,10) filled with random number from 0 to 100 
gram=tf.random.uniform(shape=(10,10), minval=0, maxval=100,dtype=tf.int32) 

# defining a column vector filled with 10,20 ....
thresh=tf.constant([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90], shape=[10,1],dtype=tf.int32) 

# calculate less 
outputs=tf.math.less(gram,thresh)
```

Using `int32` or `float32` leads to the same result. Actually the comparisons are wrong, here the output:

```
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
print(sess.run(gram))
print(sess.run(outputs))


gram tensor with random values

[[19 58  2 41 50 28 42  4 40 31]
 [71 33 38 16 56  2 26 83 10 33]
 [44 62 54 48 28 27 83 62  7 67]
 [19 96 65 12 55 30 98  8  9 47]
 [62 98 39 60 60 84 17 66  2 44]
 [64 64 37 87 96 48 22 78 62 86]
 [ 8 62 65 58 62 18 67 27  3  5]
 [87 73  4 48  3 33 23 71 21 43]
 [ 3 10 26 44 22  1  7 12  5 70]
 [18  6 10 63  2 69  5 43 58 10]]


corresponding boolean mask

 [[False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False  True False False False]
 [ True  True False False  True False  True False  True False]
 [False False  True False False False  True False False False]
 [False False False  True False  True False False False False]
 [False  True False  True  True False  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True False  True False  True  True  True  True]
 [False  True False  True False  True False  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]]
```

Compare the gram matrix and the result, for example (`row 8, column 2`) 73<70 -> `False`, but instead there is a `TRUE`. How can i fix this and where does it come from. Thanks

Comment: row versus column would explain that

Comment: Did i misinterpreted a broadcasting rule ? actually when i transform ´thresh´ into a row vector, the same problem appears, so sorry dont get your advice

Comment: Each time you call `run` the tensor `gram` will get a new random value. Do `print(*sess.run([gram, outputs]), sep='\n')` to see the correctly corresponding values of `gram` and `outputs`.

Comment: Thanks thats it, safed my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the Comment Section, for the benefit of the community.

As jdehesa correctly mentioned, Each time when you call `run` the tensor `gram` will get a new random value because you are using `tf.random`. To get same value on every `run` use `tf.constant`.

The code,

```
print(sess.run(gram))
print(sess.run(outputs))
```

can be replaced with has resolved the issue

```
print(sess.run([gram, outputs]))
```

Complete working code is shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
  inputs=tf.ones((2,10,10,5))
  # generate random tensor in shape (10,10) filled with random number from 0 to 100
  gram=tf.random.uniform(shape=(10,10), minval=0, maxval=100,dtype=tf.int32) 
  # defining a column vector filled with 10,20 ....
  thresh=tf.constant([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90], shape=[10,1],dtype=tf.int32) 
  # calculate less 
  outputs=tf.math.less(gram,thresh)
  print(*sess.run([gram, outputs]), sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
[[79 44 24 67 53 90  0 57 74 86]
 [47 17 24 81 16 12 22 52 63 70]
 [17 94 71 76 23 66 76 59 77 19]
 [17 43 12 90 27 28 27 89 39 20]
 [22 49 38 49 56 70 77 40 71 13]
 [29 73  2 45 30  2 88 65 65 88]
 [79 15 31 44 19  2 74  4  7 35]
 [89 67 76 66  4 14 63 29 90  6]
 [86 51 61 17 79 78 64 67 33 63]
 [45 16 30 93 75 42 86 93 63 84]]

[[False False False False False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False False False False False]
 [ True False False False False False False False False  True]
 [ True False  True False  True  True  True False False  True]
 [ True False  True False False False False False False  True]
 [ True False  True  True  True  True False False False False]
 [False  True  True  True  True  True False  True  True  True]
 [False  True False  True  True  True  True  True False  True]
 [False  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True False  True  True  True False  True  True]]
```